# Bubble sort only outputs 0's

Tags: java

So I'm having a problem with my code. I had to write a program that bubble sorts through an external text file(Which is basically a list of random numbers in random order). So I tried following through my professor's steps, and even though I did, I don't get the correct output. The output is supposed to look like this:

1   2   2   2   3   3   5   5   6   6   11  13  13  13  13  16  17  17  19  25  27  27  33  34  37  37  43  45  49  51  51  52  54  55  57  57  58  60  63  64  66  75  79  79  81  85  87  90  92  92  94  95  95  97  97  99  107 109 109 111 113 113 115 116 118 121 121 125 129 132 133 133 133 134 144 144 145 148 149 151 155 155 156 156 156 159 159 162 164 165 165 167 167 168 171 173 178 179 181 183 186 186 190 191 200 203 203 203 204 205 206 207 207 207 208 209 209 210 210 215 216 217 220 220 222 223 225 228 229 230 231 233 234 235 235 238 239 239 242 245 251 252 253 258 263 268 269 271 274 276 278 278 289 296 299 301 303 304 305 306 308 308 310 311 316 319 321 321 322 323 326 329 330 333 335 338 339 340 340 345 349 350 353 353 354 355 355 356 357 358 359 362 366 366 368 374 374 376 379 379 382 386 388 392 393 394 396 396 398 399 399 399 399 401 401 401 405 407 408 413 414 415 416 416 417 418 418 420 424 426 430 432 436 436 438 440 442 442 446 446 448 449 451 456 456 457 458 460 461 462 463 470 476 477 480 480 482 484 485 487 490 490 495 501 502 504 511 511 511 511 513 513 513 514 515 518 519 523 526 527 529 531 534 534 536 537 538 538 539 540 544 545 550 554 555 558 559 559 560 561 564 567 568 568 569 571 572 574 575 578 580 580 580 581 581 582 583 583 583 584 585 585 585 587 588 590 591 596 599 604 606 614 615 616 616 617 618 620 625 628 631 631 634 635 635 639 642 647 654 654 655 659 659 659 664 666 666 669 669 672 676 678 678 684 684 685 687 687 689 690 692 692 695 698 699 704 707 707 707 717 717 717 717 717 719 719 729 730 734 734 736 736 738 740 740 749 751 752 753 754 754 754 755 759 761 763 763 768 772 778 780 783 785 786 790 792 793 795 796 798 799 799 800 802 813 813 817 820 820 821 822 826 826 827 827 829 830 830 831 832 833 835 836 837 841 846 853 854 857 857 858 858 861 866 868 868 869 872 877 879 880 881 882 888 898 909 910 914 919 919 920 920 921 927 930 931 934 934 938 943 944 945 950 953 955 957 960 962 966 968 970 971 974 975 981 989 995 998 999 999

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog481a
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Guest\\Documents\\java programs\\Prog121\\sort.in"));
        String line = kbReader.nextLine();
        String[] l1 = line.split("\n");
        int[] a = new int[l1.length];
        int temp;
        boolean fixed = true;
        while(fixed)
        {
            fixed = false;
        for(int i = 0; i<a.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
                temp = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = a[i];
                a[i] = temp;
                fixed = true;
            }
        }
       }
       for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
       {
           System.out.println(a[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

So everything compiles, but my output displays 0 and the program stops. Now I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong in my code. I've been trying to figure it out, but have run out of ideas of where to look. Could someone please provide some guidance/feedback on what's happening and how I can fix this? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: But you never fill your array. So it's a full array of 0's (default value for an int).

Comment: You are only reading one line. i.e. readLine() only reads one line.  And the one number you do get, you don't put into your array, so it will be `0`  This is where a debugger would help you understand what your program is doing so I suggest you use it to step through your code as see what it is doing.

Comment: Also, your `fixed` variable is inverted.  I would expect `while(!fixed)` and `fixed = false;` when you swap two values.

Answer (score 2):

you never put anything in array ***a***. Int array's initialize everything as 0. Split on " " (space) instead. AND! you need to change it from string to int do this via:

```
Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never store any data in `a`. Since the values in `a` are initialized to 0's, you are essentially just sorting an array of all 0's.

You have:

```
String[] l1 = line.split("\n");
int[] a = new int[l1.length];
```

You split the line into `l1` (although not correctly; you specify '\n' but your tokens are split by ' '), and you're part of the way there, but you need to finish the step of parsing each of the tokens into `int`s and sticking them in `a`.

[`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) will help you with that.